# Android aSmack - How to make custom message extension for file sending?

Tags: android, xmpp, asmack

I'm trying to implement offline file extension for my chat application. I'm using PacketExtension and EmbeddedExtensionProvider for adding and parsing custom extension. I can see that values and tags are added while sending message, but at receiver end these are absent. What i'm doing wrong ?

Sending message:

```
<message id="224K2-7" to="testfirzan@sushant" type="chat">
    <body>hi</body>
    <custom xmlns="jabber2:x2:oob2">
      <url>URL</url>
      <desc>Description</desc>
    </custom>
</message>
```

Receiving message:

```
System.out(734): EmbeddedExtensionProvider

<message id="224K2-7" to="testfirzan@sushant" from="testsushant@sushant/Smack" type="chat">
    <body>hi</body>
    <custom xmlns="jabber2:x2:oob2"></custom>
</message>

File Extension description:(734): <custom xmlns="jabber2:x2:oob2"></custom>
```

Packet extension and provider manager code:

```
public class FileExtension implements PacketExtension {

public static final String ELEMENT = "custom";
public static final String NAMESPACE = "jabber2:x2:oob2";

String description;
String url;

@Override
public String getElementName() {
    return "custom";
}

@Override
public String getNamespace() {
    return "jabber2:x2:oob2";
}

@Override
public String toXML() {

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("<" + getElementName() + " xmlns=\"" + getNamespace()
            + "\">");
    if (url != null) {
        builder.append("<url>").append(url).append("</url>");
    }
    if (description != null) {
        builder.append("<desc>").append(description).append("</desc>");
    }
    builder.append("</" + getElementName() + ">");
    return builder.toString();
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String imageUrl) {
    this.url = imageUrl;
}

public static class FileExtensionProvider extends EmbeddedExtensionProvider {

    @Override
    protected PacketExtension createReturnExtension(String currentElement,
            String currentNamespace, Map<String, String> attributeMap,
            List<? extends PacketExtension> content) {

        System.out.println("EmbeddedExtensionProvider");
        return new FileExtension();
    }
}
}
```

Registering provider :

```
ProviderManager.getInstance().addExtensionProvider(
            FileExtension.ELEMENT, FileExtension.NAMESPACE,
            new FileExtension.FileExtensionProvider());
```

While sending message :

```
FileExtension fileExt = new FileExtension("URL");
    fileExt.setDescription("Description");
    fileExt.setUrl("URL");

    msg.addExtension(fileExt);
```

After receiving message :

```
FileExtension fileExt = (FileExtension) message
                            .getExtension("jabber2:x2:oob2");

                    Log.i("File Extension description:", fileExt.toXML());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following is the complete solution for making custom extension with aSmack:

1st i had to create PacketExtension:

```
public class ExtensionFile implements PacketExtension {

    public static final String ELEMENT = "file";
    public static final String NAMESPACE = "file:namespace";

    private String fileURL;
    private String fileSize;

    @Override
    public String getElementName() {
        return ELEMENT;
    }

    @Override
    public String getNamespace() {
        return NAMESPACE;
    }

    @Override
    public String toXML() {

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("<" + getElementName() + " xmlns=\"" + getNamespace()
            + "\">");
        if (fileURL != null) {
            builder.append("<fileURL>").append(fileURL).append("</fileURL>");
        }
        if (fileSize != null) {
            builder.append("<fileSize>").append(fileSize).append("</fileSize>");
        }
        builder.append("</" + getElementName() + ">");
        return builder.toString();
    }

    public void setFileURL(String fileURL) {
        this.fileURL = fileURL;
    }

    public String getFileURL() {
        return fileURL;
    }

    public void setFileSize(String fileSize) {
        this.fileSize = fileSize;
    }

    public String getFileSize() {
        return fileSize;
    }
}
```

Then provider to parse this packet:

```
public class ExtensionProviderFile implements PacketExtensionProvider {

@Override
public PacketExtension parseExtension(XmlPullParser parser)
        throws Exception {

    ExtensionFile fileExt = new ExtensionFile();

    int eventType = parser.next();

    while (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {

        String name = parser.getName();

        switch (parser.getEventType()) {

            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                if (name.equals("fileURL")) {

                    fileExt.setFileURL(parser.nextText());
                } else if (name.equals("fileSize")) {

                    fileExt.setFileSize(parser.nextText());
                }
        }

        eventType = parser.next();
    }

    return fileExt;
}
}
```

Sending message with file extension:

```
private void sendMessage(String recipient, String message){

    Message msg = new Message(recipient,Message.Type.chat);
    msg.setBody(message);

    //Create extension and set values
    ExtensionFile fileExt = new ExtensionFile();
    fileExt.setFileURL("http://www.example.com/upload_files/"+ abc.jpg);
    fileExt.setFileSize(fileSize);

    //add extension to message
    msg.addExtension(fileExt);

    //send message
    xmppConnection.sendPacket(msg);
}
```

To receive this message implement `PacketListener` and override `processPacket()`:

```
@Override
public void processPacket(Packet packet) {

    Message message = (Message) packet;

    //Get extension from message
    ExtensionFile extFile = (ExtensionFile) message
                    .getExtension("file:namespace");

    if (extFile != null) {

        //Get values from extension
        String filePath = extFile.getFileURL();
        String fileSize = extFile.getFileSize();

        System.out.println("Message :" + message.getBody() + " File url:" + filePath + " File size:" + fileSize);
    }
}
```

and add this provide before connecting to xmpp server:

```
ProviderManager.getInstance().addExtensionProvider(
            ExtensionFile.ELEMENT, ExtensionFile.NAMESPACE,
            new ExtensionProviderFile());
```

Comment: You need to escape the XML in the toXml() method.

Comment: @Flow not necessarily needed. `toXml()` can be use to view message in xml format. `ProviderManager` parses the `ExtensionFile`.

Comment: You must always escape Strings for XML. For example fileURL could contain characters which need to be escaped.

Comment: @Flow i think that's what `ExtensionProviderFile` does in this case.

Comment: No, providers are responsible for deserialization. toXml() serializes a stanza.

Comment: It seems PacketExtension is deprecated in Smack 4.1.7, we have to extend DataPacketExtension, but it expects sessionID, seq & data as arguments. How to set these data while sending message? any idea?

Comment: Ya, got the answer. need to extend ExtensionElementProvider.

Comment: @Vikram Bhati I used `DefaultExtensionElement` from newer api.

Comment: Ok. As per this (https://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/56512#251180) site I worked with ExtensionElementProvider. I had tried with DefaultExtensionElement but it's breaking connection.

Comment: how to get attribute value
My message is    <message id='eMC4I-4'
         to='919868184369@ejabberchat.techmaster.in'
         type='chat'>
  <body>hg</body>
  <pnr xmlns='pnr:namespace'
       pnrType='1'>test</pnr>  
</message>
How can i get pnrtype value by above answer

Answer (score 1):

In latest version of Smack 4.1.7, PacketExtensionProvider is removed ([see this](https://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/56512#251180)). So ExtensionProviderFile can be created after extending ExtensionElementProvider. Please check below code -

```
public class ExtensionProviderFile extends ExtensionElementProvider {

    @Override
    public Element parse(XmlPullParser parser, int initialDepth) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException, SmackException {

        ChatExtension extensionFile = new ChatExtension();

        int eventType = parser.next();

        while (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG){
            String name = parser.getName();

            switch (parser.getEventType()) {

                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:

                    if (name.equals("fileName")) {
                        extensionFile.setFileName(parser.nextText());
                    }

                    else if (name.equals("fullName")) {
                        extensionFile.setFullName(parser.nextText());
                    }

            }

            eventType = parser.next();
        }

        return extensionFile;
    }
}
```

Hope this will help someone.